# Chrome Geolocation extension

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome geolocation extension. Why does it give location coordinates without ever asking the user for permission, not even on first install ?:S

Comment: Have you installed it from your own folder? Or have you installed the *.crx file?

Comment: I have installed it from my own folder.

Answer (score 3):

When you install the extension you grant it permission to access various things. If it's one you've developed, then it will assume that you've granted it permission. Users will get a box like this, with whatever APIs you've used:

[image: Extension popup]

Comment: so, shouldn't it display a notification asking for permission(whenever ur click on the extension icon) whether u want to allow the extension to track down your location ?

Comment: yea..well, I uninstalled chrome and installed it again and tried it but it still works without any permission notification. 

P.S. I haven't install the extension through .crx file. It's local.

Comment: This is unsettling, as the notification (on first install) usually informs the user about what info will be used. I don't recall if  geolocation is explicitly mentioned. Chrome browser "Under the hood" lets you check what apps (or maybe websites) you've given permission  (on an exception basis) to access your location, assuming that you set "no access to location" as default. I wonder how, or IF it interacts with Chrome extensions. EDIT Here's more info about "Under the Hood" and location  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181379/w3c-geolocation-api-not-working-in-chrome/6181566#6181566

Comment: Is it because I'm not actually installing it using a .crx file but I am just loading the folder from my desktop.

But even If I load, I am supposed to get a notification permission of the following type which is currently not being asked :
http://tinyurl.com/6k7jd6a