# Chrome geolocation not working on any site

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, geolocation

I'm trying to build a site based on geolocation, and I'm thinking of using html5 geolocation.

I built the w3c code and it wouldn't work for me on google chrome, then I noticed that none of the online examples work for me on google chrome:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

http://html5demos.com/geo

The strange thing is that I do see the prompt that asks me whether I want to grant permission to access location info, but after that it doesn't work. I checked my chrome settings and it is on "ask whether to grant permission to website".

Instead, on safari on the same machine it is working fine.

I'm on an iMac (end of 2012) with mavericks if this can help somehow.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've already tried this solution: [W3C Geolocation API not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181379/w3c-geolocation-api-not-working-in-chrome?rq=1)

Comment: Can you test using iphone android?

Comment: What version of Google Chrome are you using?

Comment: Do you have your local server running?

Comment: See the answer in the link to other problem: 

_Because of security restrictions, resources loaded with the file:/// scheme are not allowed access to location_

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for answering

@BorisIvanov it wouldn't make sense to test on iphone android, it works fine for me on safari on the same computer

Comment: @BinaryBrain Version 30.0.1599.101 (latest version)

Comment: @AntoJurkovic The two links in my post aren't working either, and they aren't on local server / file protocol.

Comment: @aberonni hi i am having the same issue, i hope you solved this issue. Please share your answer

Comment: @ErmaIsabel it actually solved itself after a while. I can't remember what did it, but I believe that a system reboot solved the issue at the end. It doesn't seem to be documented so I think it is just a random bug that is solved with a reboot/clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation over HTTP will no longer work, since non-secure geolocation is deprecated:

> We want to start applying the concepts in https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/ to features that have already shipped and which do not meet the (new, not present at the time) requirements. In particular, this approximately requires that powerful features only be accessible on "secure origins" (such as HTTPS) where the full ancestor chain is also secure.
>
> We want to start by requiring secure origins for these existing features:

```
Geolocation — requires secure origins as of M50
Device motion / orientation
EME
getUserMedia
AppCache
```

> As with gradually marking HTTP as non-secure, we expect to gradually migrate these features to secure-only, based on thresholds of usage, starting with lowest usage and moving towards higher. We also expect to gradually indicate in the UX that the features are deprecated for non-secure origins.
>
> The deprecation strategy for each of these features is not decided on and may very well differ from feature to feature. We don’t currently know what the thresholds will be, or how heavily used the features are on what kinds of origins. We are in the process of gathering data, and will report back when we have it. There are no firm plans at all at this time, other than eventual deprecation. We intend for this to stimulate a public discussion of the best way to approach this deprecation. So, to that point, we'd love to hear what the community thinks.
>
> Testing a Deprecated Powerful Feature
>   After a feature has been deprecated, if you are a developer that needs to keep testing a feature on a server that does not have a valid certificate, you have two options:
>
> localhost is treated as a secure origin over HTTP, so if you're able to run your server from localhost, you should be able to test the feature on that server.
>
> You can run chrome with the --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com" flag (replacing "example.com" with the origin you actually want to test), which will treat that origin as secure for this session. Note that you also need to include the --user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir to create a fresh testing profile for the flag to work.

**References**

- [Deprecating Powerful Features on Insecure Origins](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)
- [Removal of geolocation from insecure origins](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=561641)