# Google HTML 5 Geolocation 'use my location' only working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, geolocation

I have a button that is meant to check your location and in return show you the closest locations.

I've got it working perfectly in Firefox, and it wasn't on a live domain before but on a development server and I saw several resources that supported the thought that it had to be on a live domain for html 5 geolocation to work in Chrome.

Now we have moved to the real domain, and still the same results, only Firefox is working and in Chrome and I'm pretty sure Safari it says 'unable to retrieve location' meaning there was an error. I've made sure to check that Chrome isn't blocking the site for requesting my location (no popup comes up to click yes/no) although it is definitely activated in my settings. Same result on different PC's.

Any thoughts what could block this? It's on a live domain.

This is my code:

```
function geoFindMe() {

var output = $('.location-use');

if (!navigator.geolocation){
   $(".location-use").html('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
return;
}

 function success(position) {
 var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
 var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

  //find nearest restaurant location from these lat n long
  NearestLoc( latitude, longitude );

};



 function error() {
   $(".location-use").html('Unable to retrieve your location');
 };

$(".location-use").html('Locating...');

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
 }
```

Comment: Check this post [Geolocation API not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181379/w3c-geolocation-api-not-working-in-chrome)
for probable solution.

Comment: Thank you, seems HTTPS is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

This answer is here (thanks user3186314), Chrome requires HTTPS