# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not allowed on "file:///C:/" based access

Tags: html, google-chrome, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML 5 Geo Location Prompt in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423938/html-5-geo-location-prompt-in-chrome)

I've been looking at geolocation in Html 5. I'm using Chrome (12) and am accessing the html file using a path like this: file:///C:/_Development/Examples/Html5/boilerplate.html

I'm getting the little geolocation icon in the search bar that says that the location has been blocked from tracking your location.

Note that I don't have any exceptions setup at all...

Can this be done or do I need to host the file on a web server? If it can't be done, why can't it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a duplicate of this question:

> [HTML 5 Geo Location Prompt in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423938/html-5-geo-location-prompt-in-chrome)

It seems that chrome has security restrictions on accessing geolocation data locally. You need to host the file to use the data.  A workaround with python is available in the previous question.

Comment: Thanks for the referent to the other question. The python option is interesting, didn't know you could do that. I suspect that I will be using that a lot from now on. Your answer's therefore been very valuable! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. You could also use node to host the file if you wanted to be trendy haha

Comment: I am facing same issue, I cannot switch to python nor can host the page as the content is dynamic and has to be loaded form local drive only. Any other help?