# Google Maps API v3 Geolocation not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm using Google Maps API v3 Geolocation to get the users actual location. I found this post from Google Developers:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Here my code (equals to the code of Google Maps example):

```
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>

<script>
// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
// prompted by your browser. If you see a blank space instead of the map, this
// is probably because you have denied permission for location sharing.

var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="entry-content">
            <div class="blogtitle">IT</div><p>&nbsp;</p></td><td> </td><td><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr></tbody></table><p>&nbsp;</p>
            <div id="map-canvas"></div><!-- map-canvas end -->
        </div><!-- entry-content end -->
    </div><!-- container end -->
</body>
```

This works quite fine in Firefox but not in Google Chrome & Safari. I think because Chrome & Safari are webkit browsers. But I don't know how to fix it.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: what bit of it doesn't work?  You don't see the map, you're not able to get the user's location, you get a javascript error?

Comment: There comes an error: `Error: The Geolocation service failed.` and then the marker points in a forest somewhere in Russia (I'm in Switzerland...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725594/html-navigator-user-denied-geolocation)

> It appears this is a security restriction for the file protocol. Looks like you are going to need to host it locally from a server.

I've tested your code with a local server and it just works fine.
Hope I could help.

Comment: Hmm. Thank you, you know how I can host it from a local server? An example?

Comment: Depends on which OS you are using. I'm using MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/) for OSX. If you are using Windows check out XAMP. Just put your html/php/css/whatsoever files in the htdocs folder and start up the server. Here's a small FAQ for MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/faq.html)

Comment: You mean XAMPP? I'm using windows. In my company we don't use XAMPP. We use IIS. You know how to host it in this way?

Comment: Yes, i meant XAMPP. I have no clue about IIS. Just give XAMPP a try, it's very straight forward and easy to use!

Comment: I already know XAMPP. I use it at home to create some test website (just to improve my HTML/HTML5,CSS/CSS3 and jQuery skills). But in our company they don't want to use XAMPP because they use IIS many years before :) But thank you for trying to help me, I think I will figure it out and post the solution here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [HTML5 geolocation API](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html#w3c)instead of Google Maps' one for the browsers you are having problems with.

You can find the reference [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/)