# How can I get a client location using the Google Map (Geocoding) Javascript API using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geolocation

There are plenty of examples all over the internet, including stakoverflow, of getting location information. But every single one that I find uses HTML to include the library (`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>`) and display the information. I need to get the client location from a script, not a web page. I just need to get the location information - I don't need to display it. No HTNML - just javascript.

I've tried several of the examples found on this site, but they all use the `navigator.geolocation` or `google.maps` classes, neither of which are recognized by Google Scripting. I've tried to include a resource, but maps nor navigator or any of the required APIs are in the list. I've even attempted to find a RESTful way to use the API and get a JSON response; found nothing even close.

The example used in several places is [this one on developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation), including several appearances in stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588940/google-maps-api-v3-geolocation-not-working-in-google-chrome).

I suppose it could be a very "newbie" issue, but I'm flummoxed!

Comment: Do you mean "geolocation" rather than ["geocoding"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) in the title?