# Geolocation error: User denied geolocation prompt

Tags: geolocation, leaflet

I loaded my Leaflet Map on a Server. I have a GPS Function on my Map. But every time I get the error alert "Geolocation error: User denied geolocation prompt."

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html navigator "User denied Geolocation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725594/html-navigator-user-denied-geolocation)

Comment: Plus add some code and some more information about the error

Answer (score 4):

You're probably not using **https**. Most modern browsers require https to use geolocation. You can check it in Mozillas [Browser Compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: That doesn't help much for local app development on FF v71 when the ionic server only issues a http server. Fortunately Vivaldi v2.10.1745.21 is working with this http method and geo is working. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this on Mac.

```
brew install nss
```

then

```
mkcert -install
```

[then you need to allow location in your security settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/243Fk.png)

[After that it worked for me in firefox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps01X.png)

[See also how to do https on localhost.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397809/create-a-trusted-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-for-use-with-express-node)

Comment: I recently upgraded macOS and I got this error because geolocation services were disabled by default after that upgrade. I only had to re-enable it in the system settings, but I did not have to install anything with `brew`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check api if you are using any webview. In my case I am trying to load map in webview using flutter in mobile device and I ran into same problem.
I was using [InAppWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) to load map.
There I had the same issue which is "Geolocation error: User denied geolocation prompt".
So later I noticed I had to use `androidOnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` parameter in `InAppWebView`.
I am sure other package has same method.