# Chrome getUserMedia Not Requesting Permission Locally

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm attempting to play around with navigator.getUserMedia in Chrome; however, it is not requesting permission when served locally (file:///whatever/index.html), but does on JSFiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/EBsvq/ ) and other sites.

Does anyone know the reason for this? Do I need to somehow reset my permissions?

Here is what I am using locally:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <button id="btn">Start</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
   /*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
   //JQuery goes here
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.getUserMedia;

  $(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
      navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, 
      function(){
        alert('success');
      },
      function (err) {
        alert('fail: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      }); }); });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Chrome blocks a lot of stuff on `file:///` URIs without reporting a security error (eg. [Geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5423938/8655)).  Your best option is to run from a local webserver, if you have Python installed try [SimpleHTTPServer](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python).

Comment: This is correct: getUserMedia only works when run from a file on a server. It won't work from file:// URLs. You will get a `PERMISSION_DENIED: 1` error, but that's not very intuitive!

Comment: @SamDutton: I filed a bug report asking for a more intuitive error message: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257104

Comment: Guys, I have WAMP and I have the exact same problem! It works fine while on the "real" web.. localhost, I receive the error message i setup. Any ideas???

Comment: Why in the hell wouldn't you be allowed to use a camera on your own system?  Stupid

Comment: Mac users: Python comes ready-installed so this is a very simple & quick solution

Comment: getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Comment: For the lazy: Run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` from the directory with your file and navigate to http://localhost:8000

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag from the command line when opening chrome to be able to use `getUserMedia` from a local file system.

Comment: Much faster than setting up a web server for a simple test

Comment: I tried but it didn't seem to work. I'm using Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 m.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem, but related to microphone access.
Chrome blocks device access if you serve your file via file://(note that on Microsoft Edge and Firefox it worked via file:://).

One solution i've found for Chrome:

1. open chrome an type in the URL chrome://version/
2. copy the value of "Command Line" field in your command line and append 
   --allow-file-access-from-files and run it
3. after Chrome opened and enter your file:// url.

For starting Chrome always like that, right click on Chrome icon, and then click on properties. In the Shortcut tab append to the Target value all the command line parameters from 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little non-trivial how to do the command line arg in OS X. It will usually look like this

```
"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

If you are a freak like me, and put your apps in `~/Applications`, then it will be

```
"/Users/yougohere/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

If neither of those are working, then type `chrome://version` in your Chrome address bar, and it will tell you what "command line" invocation you should be using. Just add `--allow-file-access-from-files` to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing Simple Server ( light weight ) , one click install , can be downloaded [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9PX6WbpRXHNNjZfWEREV1QtYUE/edit)

Once it is installed , refer the app to the page you want to run.