# getUserMedia() permission denied

Tags: html, webrtc

I am trying to test out screen sharing using `getUserMedia()`. I have Chrome version 28 and the `getUserMedia()` screen capturing flag enabled, yet I still get permission denied errors.

On this [screen capture demo](http://simpl.info/screencapture/), I get the following error:

> getUserMedia error:  NavigatorUserMediaError {code: 1, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1}

While, on [this screen capture demo](https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/screenshare.html), I get the following demo:

> PERMISSION_DENIED. Are you no SSL?

I never got any prompts about sharing when visiting the sites. Why does my browser deny permission to screen share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second demo you mentioned ([this one](https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/screenshare.html)) works for me on Chrome 28.

It sounds like you enabled the flag, but make sure the one called `Enable screen capture support in getUserMedia()` is enabled in `chrome://flags` (and that you have restarted Chrome since enabling that).

Comment: This is not working for me even using SSL, and enabling the flags, I am using `Chrome Version 29.0.1547.62 m`

Comment: try using https. If you are not using SSL, it will not work for new chrome versions

Answer (score 13):

I had the same permission denied problem.
I solved it simply clicking in

[image: Chrome video icon disabled video]

And enabling the "Ask me to enable video..." option

Reload page and it will ask again if you want to load the webcam.
That worked for me.

Comment: Working solution for me

Answer (score 7):

For screen capture with getUserMedia, you need to use HTTPS. (Apologies if you followed a link of mine which didn't have that!)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same situation and my reason is that the camera is **already used** by another page. I closed the page, retry and everything is alright.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just because I didn't run the webpage from a local server (I was simply opening my html page in chrome through the file system).

Using a basic server like mamp fixed it!

Comment: this was the problem for me. apparently chrome will you give a PermissionDeniedError on file:// URLS. related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723699/chrome-getusermedia-not-requesting-permission-locally