# permission denied error using WebRTC with google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

I am trying to access my local camera using WebRTC and the console log displays this message:

```
NavigatorUserMediaError
    constraintName: "" 
    message: ""
    name: "PermissionDeniedError"
```

what could it be?

google version: 41.0.2272.76 m

Comment: Check this link [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578199/getusermedia-permission-denied

Comment: Are you actually allowing the camera(in the far right of the url field)?

Comment: @BenjaminTrent yes, i am allowing the camera. in the [content settings->Media] the the first option "Ask me when a site requires access to your camera and microphone" is selected.

Comment: Do you have multiple cameras attached? Does it work in FireFox? What OS are you running? What type of camera? What are your media constraints? I know these are tons of questions but specific cameras only support specific constraints on different platforms.

Comment: I tried uninstalling chrome and installing it again... and all of a sudden it was working, but after i tried my webapp a few times the same thing happened again. Any ideas why ?