# Issue in Html 5 Qr code reader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qr-code

I am developing a mobile application, in which it uses QR code scanner.I am using the following code `http://dwa012.github.io/html5-qrcode/`. As per the instruction given in the 'Readme' file. I have wirtten the following code.

```
 <div  class="center" id="reader" style="width:300px;height:250px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#reader').html5_qrcode(function(data){
         // do something when code is read
    },
    function(error){
        //show read errors 
    }, function(videoError){
        //the video stream could be opened
    }
);




</script>
</div>
```

But iam not getting the output, its not opening the webcam. 
Please help in getting where i went wrong.

Comment: i don't think it will work in mobile webview. Because there is no direct access to camera up to now in mobile browsers..

Comment: As of now, I need to open in pc atleast

Comment: I could able to access the webcam from browser but Iam unable to see the display.

Answer (score 0):

If the github example page works for you, it sounds like you might not be running a server. [See if this stackoverflow question helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723699/chrome-getusermedia-not-requesting-permission-locally).