# GetUserMedia not working on Macbook Pro

Tags: html, macos, getusermedia

I have been doing some experiments with the `GetUserMedia` API (specifically following [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)).

When using my Macbook pro and any version of the `getUserMedia` API (all vendor-prefixed versions) I get the following message:

> getUserMedia() not supported in your browser.

I do not know why.  I am have tried using the latest versions of Chrome Canary, Firefox and Chrome (40+), all of which should support it (I literally can't update my browsers any more). Additionally, my Macbook Pro is an `Early 2011` running `OS X 10.10.1` and has a built in webcam that I am using with Skype regularly.

I have tried the identical code with an external camera on a Windows computer and everything works , so perhaps it is a problem with my Macbook Pro although I am not sure what the issue would be.

Comment: I tried the examples from that tutorial "Feature detection" and "Gaining access to an input device", and they work fine for me on a 2010 Macbook Air running 10.10.1 as well. So whatever the issue is, it's not a general issue with older Macs.

Comment: A shot in the dark, but: how did you access your test page on both laptops? Was it a `file:///` url, or did you access it through a web server? I'm asking because of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723699/chrome-getusermedia-not-requesting-permission-locally).

Comment: It was through a local web  server, I thought about that too but when visiting external websites I get the same error.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but what are your permission settings for "Media" in chrome://settings/content ? I get that you experience that issue cross-browser, but still.

Comment: Also, it seems that quite a lot of people have an issue with their Facetime camera under Yosemite, but not necessarily across all apps - some have reported that Skype works, while other apps do not. Try confirming that the built-in Facetime app works.

Comment: It does work with facetime and the `Media` settings are set to "allow". But thank you  for your help, I did not know about the `chrome://settings/content` in Chrome and that will come in handy.

Comment: You can also manage all permissions by clicking on the favicon, on the left end of the URL bar. But regarding your issue - sorry, I'm all out of ideas at the moment, except for maybe creating a new OSX user account and trying once more under that account.