# Webcam not displaying, when using getUserMedia in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

html code for video and canvas tag

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay controls></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
```

javascript file .js

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia              || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||   navigator.msGetUserMedia;
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;


if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, successCallback, errorCallback);
} else {
console.log('Native device media streaming (getUserMedia) not supported in this browser.');
// Display a friendly "sorry" message to the user.
}
```

Comment: it's better reference Google adapter.js, code will be more simple. And as curriegrr said you need include successCallback and errorCallback functions.

Comment: please look: http://jsfiddle.net/alexan/5qf831k4/

Answer (score 0):

Is this all of your JavaScript? If it is, you have not defined successCallback and errorCallback functions. See below.

```js
var errorCallback = function(e) {
  console.log('Reeeejected!', e);
};

var successCallback = function(localMediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
}
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;


if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia({
    video: true
  }, successCallback, errorCallback);
} else {
  console.log('Native device media streaming (getUserMedia) not supported in this browser.');
  // Display a friendly "sorry" message to the user.
}
```

If you have defined those functions, it might also come down to how you are running it. If you are running from file and in Chrome it is not supported. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13725688/496694 Try testing with another browser or using a webserver.