# How to ask Chrome getUserMedia Permissions from blob iframe?

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Im developing chrome extension, from which i`d like to add widget on any page.
I have code, that displaying my widget from plain html:

```
 var blob = new Blob([myWidgetHtmlPage], {type : 'text/html'});
 myIframe.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

but when i`m asking for getting user media, nothing happening. I saw question [Chrome getUserMedia Not Requesting Permission Locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723699/chrome-getusermedia-not-requesting-permission-locally), but how about asking for user media from **blob:https://www.google.com/457de9cb-5349-4a34-9d72-6e57162e4161** ( when iframe creating from blob on main google page)

Comment: Would declaring `audioCapture` and `videoCapture` be of help in this scenario? Its indicated in the [Declare permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions) that the 2 are needed to capture audio/video (if that's what the blob contains) and will be called via the `getUserMedia` API. Check out the [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) repository if it can be of help to you.

Comment: @adjuremods this permissions unavailable for extensions, just for apps