# how to get my current location on my browser

Tags: javascript, php

hey guys i'm trying to find my current location on my browser , this is my html index file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(savePosition, positionError, {timeout:10000});
      } else {
          //Geolocation is not supported by this browser
      }
  }

  // handle the error here
  function positionError(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var message = error.message;

      alert(message);
  }

  function savePosition(position) {
            $.post("geocoordinates.php", {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude});
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getLocation();">Get My Location</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and that's the geocoordinates.php file :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['lat'], $_POST['lng'])) {
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];

    $url = sprintf("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%s,%s", $lat, $lng);

    $content = file_get_contents($url); // get json content

    $metadata = json_decode($content, true); //json decoder

    if(count($metadata['results']) > 0) {
        // for format example look at url
        // https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452
        $result = $metadata['results'][0];

        // save it in db for further use
        echo $result['formatted_address'];

    }
    else {
        // no results returned
    }
}

?>
```

i found this as an answer for a previous question but when i run it on browser it gives me an error as : user denied goelocation so can any one help ?????

Comment: User must allow your website to fing its geolocation. If user denied it, you'll not be able to fetch geolocation data. Except some other ways, let's say via user's IP address

Comment: so how can i allow it as i'm the user ? @Vnuuk

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: google chrome - internet explorer - mozila firefox

Comment: @MohamedElbiheiry what u r trying to find out here? the user's location?

Comment: @Plum yes that's what i'm trying to find

Comment: @MohamedElbiheiry   What if the user deny to share location?

Comment: i don't pretty understand what do u mean of user ?? do u mean it as the browser or me who is looking for it ? @Plum

Comment: I think Mohamed Elbiheiry has this error just opened his website.. he doesn't do enything

Comment: what do u mean of " he doesn't do anything " ?

Comment: Mohamed Elbiheiry, I mean that you just open website and see this error. You don't denie browser geolocation by clicking browser's popup window

Comment: aha , if u r just look at my question i said that i found it as a correction for another question so i wanted to try it either and i found that error , i didn't say any thing else @Vnuuk

Comment: Related content: [HTML 5 Geo Location Prompt in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5423938/2943403)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<p><button class="w3-btn w3-blue" onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button></p>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
  mapholder=document.getElementById('mapholder')
  mapholder.style.height='250px';
  mapholder.style.width='100%';

  var myOptions={
  center:latlon,zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl:false,
  navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
  }

function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
      break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Please see here for more details:-http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp
Here the javascript gives the latitude and longitude and checks the exact location of you.

Comment: so do u mean that i should put this script in my index.html instead of the i have ?

Comment: ya. no php is required. When you click on the Try It button. It will show you a map with a marker where your location is.

Comment: i added it but i guess now that the problem in my browser because i have a hint whenever i try it as the browser has blocked these sites

Comment: @MohamedElbiheiry Then allow it to view your location. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest code from above all :-

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=> {
    const p=position.coords;
    console.log(p.latitude,p.longitude);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```