# Javascript GeoLocation is not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation

I'm trying to take the geolocation of the User and then do a query.
In Mozilla Firefox it works fine also in Safari.... but in Chrome it doesnt work at all.

```
window.onload = function(){
  if(navigator.geolocation){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

        var latitude = position.coords.latitude,
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(latitude + " " + longitude);

    },handleError);

    function handleError(error){
      //Handle Errors
     switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            console.log("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
           console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
           console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
    }
    }
  }else{
    // container.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not Supported for this browser/OS.";
    alert("Geolocation is not Supported for this browser/OS");
  }
};
```

And i get the `error 1`

```
User denied the request for Geolocation.
```

But i haven't denied any request, actually the popup window doesnt come up at all.

I've went to Chrome Settings > Show advanced > Privacy > Content Settings > Location allow for all.

Restarted chrome and nothing happened. I'm sure my code is 100% legit so does anyone know how to deal with it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok this was quite easy... Chrome since 20 of April 2016 has disabled the Geolocation API for insecure websites (without https)... link here

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

So dont worry..

Comment: You can bypass this limitation when you are testing on localhost, as localhost is considered secure for that check.

Comment: @Ferrybig how to do that

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to click on the area left to the address bar and change location settings there. It allows to set location options even for `file:///` and all other types

[image]

Comment: This setting kept resetting to "Blocked" the instant I clicked allow. Turned out my mac's system wide settings was disabling it.

System preferences > Security and privacy > Privacy > Location Services > Enable Chrome

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome, please have a look at the answer below:

[HTML 5 Geo Location Prompt in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423938/html-5-geo-location-prompt-in-chrome)

Comment: I run it on a server online and not in any localhost or  `file:///`