# No data is being displayed in the web page for my weather app

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

So I have been making a weather app recently . 
I tested my code and the tempreture and the country and the decription of the current weather are not being displayed . I think the problem begins after my html geolocation function. I feel the function is somehow unable to parse through the weather api data.

My code is here down below :

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }


  function showPosition(position) {
var lat = "lat= " + position.coords.latitude; 
var lon = "lon= " + position.coords.longitude;
getWeather(lat,lon);
  }

   function getWeather(lat,lon){
var urlstring = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?" + lat + "&" + lon;
$.ajax({
    url : urlstring,
    dataType : "jsonP",
    success : function(data){
        var temp = data.main.temp;
        var desc = data.weather[0].description;
        var country = data.sys.country;
        $("#desc").html(desc);
        $("#temp").html(temp);
    }
})
  }

  var ctof = $("#c/f").click(function(){
     var cel = Math.round((temp - 32) * 5 / 9);   
     var faren = Math.round((temp * 9 / 5) + 32);
     if(ctof == true){
        $("#temp").html(faren);
      }
      else{
        $("#temp").html(cel);
      }
        }) 
  });
```

I have even included my html code just for reference sake

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Web App</title></head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <header class="col-xs-12 text-center">
       <h1>Free Code Camp </h1>
       <h1>Weather App</h1>
     </header>

     <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
       <div class="text-center status">
         <p><span id="city"></span> <span id="country"></span></p>
         <p><span id="temp"><button id="#c/f">C/F</button></span></p>
         <p id="desc"></p>
       </div>
   <div class ="info">
 <div class="develop">Developed by = Shumaila Bi Shaikh</div>
 <div class="langs">Created by: HTML,CSS,ANGULARJS</div>
 </div>

 <script src="Weather.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works in the fiddle. See https://jsfiddle.net/bokav0z8/1/ The problem might be your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `console.log(desc)` or your other pieces of data? I suspect you're getting the arrays that you need, but you're trying to directly append these arrays into your `html`, which will not work...

Lines like this:

```
    $("#desc").html(desc);
    $("#temp").html(temp);
```

This will not work unless you're passing valid html strings like `<p>Hello</p>` but in this case, you're passing arrays. You need to map out how you want your data to actually be presented, and then pass it into your `.html()` calls.

Based on your data structure, that could look like this

```
let descString = "";
desc.forEach(value => descString += "<p>" + value.something + "</p>")
$("#desc").html(descString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this line:

```
var ctof = $("#c/f").click(function() {
```

When you need to select an element having characters used in CSS notation you need to escape them prefixing a **\\**. For more details see [docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/).

Hence, you need to write:

```
var ctof = $("\\#c\\/f").click(function(){
```

A second issue is in this line:

```
<p><span id="temp"><button id="#c/f">C/F</button></span></p>
```

When you get the **data.main.temp** you overwrite and so remove the button.  Therefore, change the line to:

```
<p><span id="temp"></span><button id="#c/f">C/F</button></p>
```

In order to enable geolocation in Chrome you need to enable it like shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273146/javascript-geolocation-is-not-working-on-chrome)

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2axh86L/4/)