# Geo location does not work on chrome on mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile

I have a simple function to get the users location and search it in google maps. Works fine on Chrome desktop safari mozilla mobile and web but this does not work on chrome mobile. I have seen posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273146/javascript-geolocation-is-not-working-on-chrome)  post that say it only works on https but as you can see below I am using a https url and my website is https.

```
function getLocation(Title) {
     var startPos;
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    startPos = position;
  window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/search/'+Title+'/@' + startPos.coords.latitude+','+startPos.coords.longitude);    
  });
}
```

I have tried this

```
function getLocation(Title) {
     var startPos;
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    startPos = position;
  alert(startPos.coords.longitude);    
  });
}
```

to attempt to debug the issue but I cannot get any response on chrome on mobile. It seems to be only on mobile chrome. I am using the Pixel phone to test this if that makes any difference. Please help me I am out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/)?

And what happens if you follow [the w3schools demo](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) on your pixel phone? Does it work there?

Comment: Yes this works and ive tried this on my site and it does work

Comment: What does the alert() show on your phone?

Comment: My geo  location

Comment: but on my site it doesnt work and yes my site is https

Comment: What does the `alert(startPos.coords.longitude)` show on your phone?
Your location? If it shows your location then it works right?
Or does it return empty?

Comment: it shows nothing on my phone but on every other browser it shows my lat location

Comment: This is my issue. Ive tried on friends phones and they have the exact same issue so its not a localized issue it is only an issue on chrome on their phone

Comment: Can you send the link?