# getCurrentPosition () wont display - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

So I am trying to use getCurrentPosition to display the latitude and longitude coordinates but nothing gets displayed. I test to see if the browser accepts it and the error message does not pop up.

Javascript:

```
window.onload = Location;


var x = document.getElementById("location");


function Location() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(show);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Not working";
  }

}

function show(position) {
  x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle by default runs the code in a onload event, so setting `window.onload = getLocation;` wont work as the load event has already fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if (navigator.geolocation)` method doesn't work here as `navigator.geolocation` is an empty object, regardless of whether a position can be obtained.  You can `console.log(navigator.geolocation)` to verify this.

Instead, use the error callback parameter of `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`:

```
function getLocation() {
     navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, throwError);
}

function throwError(err) {
     switch (err.code) {
         case 1: x.innerHTML = "Permission denied."; break;
         case 2: x.innerHTML = "Position unavailable."; break;
         case 3: x.innerHTML = "Request timed out."; break;
         default: x.innerHTML = "Unknown error.";
     }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError

Also, there are some significant browser quirks to be aware of.

If you are testing your site on your local filesystem, Chrome blocks geolocation requests:
[HTML 5 Geo Location Prompt in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423938/html-5-geo-location-prompt-in-chrome)

And Firefox *still* won't handle the error callback correctly (scroll down to see workarounds): [Is there a way to check if geolocation has been DECLINED with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092400/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-geolocation-has-been-declined-with-javascript)