# Geolocation in Chrome: re-prompt or return geolocation in a Google Maps web app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

i build a Google Maps Javascrip API [web app](http://artemdzyuba.ru/map.html). I used to init the map with geolocation. So it was asking the browser for permission and it worked fine.

Now my desktop Chrome simply doesn't support the geolocation in my app. I went to Properties to check the geolocation stuff, it was all right. I don't know the reason. Maybe due to the debug process or running a test on my desktop instead of my website (like an issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423938/html-5-geo-location-prompt-in-chrome)).

So what might be the problem and how can I enable geolocation on my website again? Normally I'd like to have a button to prompt geolocation if the site was blocked.

Comment: I get javascript errors on your [live site](http://artemdzyuba.ru/map.html): `Uncaught ReferenceError: handleLocationError is not defined`.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue in your question, not (just) a link to a live site that exhibits the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip, when I tried creating a mini-copy of my code on a separate page, I ended up with no geolocation at all.. It seems that something disturbiint HTTPS status which in turn causes geolocation problems. Will try to work that out, and also deal with the handLocationError

Answer (score 0):

Located the problem: something happened with HTTPS redirecting which caused geolocation not to work for it requires HTTPS connection. I fixed it in .htaccess and now it's working.