# Can't use geolocation in my local html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use geolocation in my local HTML file. But it looks like, navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition only works with https. I don't know how could I use it in my local HTML file for learning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML 5 Geo Location Prompt in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423938/html-5-geo-location-prompt-in-chrome)

Comment: For me it works with `file:///` i asume it works with `http://localhost` too. Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to use a tunneling service like [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com). Running `ngrok http 12345` with `12345` being your local server port will spin up a tunnel and give you the URL you need to access the tunnelled version of your webserver. `ngrok` offers both HTTP and **HTTPS**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that chrome has security restrictions on accessing geolocation data locally. You need to host the file to use the data..